# DropDownList is not working properly when bound to database and add item manually

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, oracle11g

I have created one webpage in ASP.net C# front end and Oracle 11g back end.
Webpage consist of 2 DropDownList, button and GridView. Among these 2 DropdownLists, DropDownList1 contain static value "QC Released" added through ListItem Collection Editor and other DropDownList2 is bounded to database.
However, in DropDwonList2 I have added "ALL" item  added through ListItem Collection Editor.

Now, when I run the webpage and select "QC Released" from DropDownList1 and any item except "ALL" from DropDownList2 I get the result in GridView.
But when I select "QC Released" from DropDownList1 and "ALL" from  DropDownList2 not getting any data in GridView though there are data for this particular query.

Please refer my code as below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=10.31.41.103/ORCL;User ID=RL_PET;Password=RL_PET;Unicode=True");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Visible = false;
    if (DropDownList1.Text == "QC Released")
    {

        con.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter a = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT PALLET_NO, DATA_STS, MERGE, PLANT_CD, RELEASE_NO,RELEASE_DATE,QC_STATUS FROM WI_PALLET WHERE MERGE = '" + DropDownList2.Text + "' AND TRANS_TYPE = 'P' AND PLANT_CD IN ('39HV','39HF') AND DATA_STS <>9 AND DATA_STS IS NOT NULL AND PALLET_NO NOT LIKE '7%' ORDER BY PALLET_NO ASC", con);
        a.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            Label1.Text = count.ToString();
            Label1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('No such Record Found')</script>");
            GridView1.Visible = false;
        }

    }
    else if (DropDownList1.Text == "QC Released" && DropDownList2.Text == "ALL")
    {
        con.Open();
        OracleDataAdapter a = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT PALLET_NO, DATA_STS, MERGE, MFG_DT, PLANT_CD, RELEASE_NO, RELEASE_DATE, QC_STATUS FROM WI_PALLET WHERE TRANS_TYPE= 'P' AND PLANT_CD IN ('39HV','39HF') AND DATA_STS IS NOT NULL AND PALLET_NO NOT LIKE '7%'  ORDER BY PALLET_NO ASC", con);
        a.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            Label1.Text = count.ToString();
            Label1.Visible = true;
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible = true;
            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('No such Record Found')</script>");
            GridView1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('No such Record Found')</script>");
        GridView1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (DropDownList1.Text == "QC Released" && DropDownList2.Text == "ALL")
```

This condition never work. Try that:

```
if (DropDownList1.Text == "QC Released" && DropDownList2.Text == "ALL") {}
else if (DropDownList1.Text == "QC Released") {}
```

Comment: need to clarify something....i have 3 items in DropDownList1 i.e. "QC Released", "QC Pending" and "Production Booked"...now for this what will be the condition?

Comment: your solution is worked but when i select "QC Pending" and "ALL" getting no records as it is in ladder if....that means if (DropDownList1.Text == "QC Released" && DropDownList2.Text == "ALL") {}
else if (DropDownList1.Text == "QC Released") {}
(DropDownList1.Text == "QC Pending" && DropDownList2.Text == "ALL") {}

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how you use conditions in query building. Try this.

```
if (DropDownList2.Text == "ALL")
        {
            switch (DropDownList1.Text)
            {
                case "QC Released": break;
                case "QC Pending": break;
                case "Production Booked": break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (DropDownList1.Text)
            {
                case "QC Released": break;
                case "QC Pending": break;
                case "Production Booked": break;
            }
        }
```